# Android Tutorial Overlay

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart, overlay

Is there any library for android kotlin that provides overlays shown below
[Overlay Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1s1Kn.png)

I have searched through different libraries like
[MaterialTapTargetPrompt](https://github.com/sjwall/MaterialTapTargetPrompt)
[TapTargetView](https://github.com/KeepSafe/TapTargetView)
but they are providing overlays in circle..
[Sample design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJ8Tg.png)